# ClearCase with Rational Application Developer unable to connect

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, ibm-rad

I've  been using RAD for a few months now, and recently the ClearCase plugin has stopped working.  Upon installation everything was gravy, but then I went ahead and installed a Adobe Flex Builder plugin which seemed to break ClearCase.  I get the error message:

> Connect to Rational ClearCase failed.  Please ensure that the proper version of clearCase is installed with the proper patches.  Consult the ClearCase SCM Adapter documentation for further details.
>
> Provider name: IBM
>
> Plugin name: Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter
>
> Plugin ID: com.rational.clearcase
>
> Version: 7.6.0.v201105111445

I should add that I managed to fix this issue once before, after the Adobe Flex install.  But now it has cropped up again, this time (seemingly) unprovoked.  I cannot for the life of me remember what I did to fix this the first time around.  There is a similar question here on stackoverflow, but the answer didn't provide me with much inspiration.

Comment: Maybe http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14219502 can help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the instance of RAD that you are using?
If it is the case, you may want to check if your RAD is based on a 64-bit eclipse.
The SCM adapter is indeed only compatible with 32-bit JRE.
See [infos about SCM adapter on 64 bit systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460547)